# How to define string variable contains spaces and quotes in bash shell

Tags: bash

A demonstrate script in *bash* build.sh is likes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
EXTRA_FLAG="-ldflags=\"-H windowsgui\""
# EXTRA_FLAG="-ldflags='-H windowsgui'"
# EXTRA_FLAG='-ldflags="-H windowsgui"'
# EXTRA_FLAG=-ldflags\="-H windowsgui"

go build ${EXTRA_FLAG}
```

I want to get the result command like: `go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui"`, but none of these variables works as expected, which giving result like:

```sh
go build '-ldflags="-H' 'windowsgui"'
# go build '-ldflags='\''-H' 'windowsgui'\'''
# go build '-ldflags="-H' 'windowsgui"'
# go build -ldflags=-H windowsgui
```

Seems the auto-generated single quote (`'`) breaks the command, then what is the correct way to define a variable like this?

Comment: The demonstration script was obviously written with POSIX shell in mind. In `bash` (or zsh, or ksh), you would use an array instead.

Comment: The demonstration script will not work in any POSIX or posix-like shell, because quotes in variables' values are treated as data, not shell syntax (the single-quotes you see are an *indication* of this, not the cause). This looks like a duplicate of ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) (Warning: avoid all suggestions involving `eval` -- that way lies madness and really weird bugs.)

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays, and as [always quote parameter expansions to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)
):

```
extra_flags=("-ldflags=-H windowsgui" "opt2" "opt3" "optN")
go build "${extra_flags[@]}"
```

It's worth noting that:

```
go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui"
```

and

```
go build "-ldflags=-H windowsgui"
```

is effectively the same. As the go executable will get three arguments, `go`, `build` and `-ldflags=-H windowsgui` and then parse the third argument itself.

Comment: Assuming that the _demonstration script_ which the OP posted is correct (and the OP wanted to achieve the **same** effect), note that the value of `EXTRA_FLAG` contains a space, and that in this example `$EXTRA_FLAG` is passed **unquoted**, which in turn means that the author of that demonstartion does want word splitting to occur, if he is thinking in terms of sh or bash. This is a different effect to what the OP claimed that he wants to achieve. So, either that demonstration script is already broken, or the OP does not know what he wants. I suspect the former.

Comment: OP mentions that they want to run the command `go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui"` which is what I provide a sane way to do.

Comment: Yes, and most likely, your approach is the desired one. I just wanted to point out that what the OP claims to be a "reference" (i.e. his "demonstration script") is doint something different. That's why I suspected that the demonstration code is already broken.

Comment: @Andreas Louv's solution do works on OP's demo script, but what if I still want to keep the `"` inside the argument? Giving another example regardless of go build:
`WORDS=('he said, "Hello, everyone!"')` `echo ${WORDS[@]}`

the terminal will print result `he said, "Hello, everyone!"` as expected, however, using `set -x`, it can tell it's `word splitting` in to **3** args: 

`echo he said, '"Hello,' 'everyone!"'`

which I may want it to be just single **one** string passing to `echo`;

And as @user1934428 mentions, my "script broken", did I mislead or missing something up?

Comment: Add the quotes, escape as needed, and expand inside qoutes.